# Redirect does not work on nginx

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm migrating an old site to Drupal (using [migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module), and I've managed directly in code all old urls to redirect to new Drupal urls using [redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module, for example:

www.mysite.com/UserProfile.php?user=5

Redirects to:

www.mysite.com/it/community/peoples/mr-max

This works very fine on my dev environment with apache, but doesn't works on live environment with nginx.

At first try with old url, I received a blank page with the message "No input file specified."

So I've changed virtual host conf from:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
}
```

to:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME index.php;
  fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
}
```

RESULT: no more "No input file specified." blank page, but redirect doesn't works and my front page is shown for all old urls.

Here's other settings from my virtual host, if can help:

```
location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
  return 403;
}
location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
  return 403;
}
location ~ (^|/)\. {
  return 403;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri @drupal;
}
location @drupal {
  # For D7 and above:
  # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME index.php;
  fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
}
```

What kind of setting I have to change/add to the above conf to make redirect working correctly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Drupal, but about nginx.

Comment: I'm asking specific configurations to make Drupal and Drupal redirect module works on nginx, where else would I ask? There is also a specific tag 'nginx' here: what should this be used for?

Comment: [On Drupal.org, in issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/2174961) if it's incompatibility between a module and server? On Server Fault if you don't know how nginx configuration works? Here if you know how server config works and just have problem with implementing proper stuff in module.

Comment: @MXT Redirect doesn't have a stable release yet, so this is very likely to be a bug report (which we can't help with here). I see you've actually posted it as such on Drupal.org already, that will most likely remain your best line of enquiry. Even Perusio's Drupal conf for Nginx has no special processing for the Redirect module, so either your general Nginx conf is incorrect (though I can't see anything wrong with it at a glance), or there's something amiss in the Redirect module. I'm not sure you'll get much help with either of those here I'm afraid, not really what we deal with

Comment: Ok guys excuse me, I'm just desperately looking for an answer. I can't know if it's a module incompatibility (yet no answers on d.org issue queue) or a simple missing vhost configuration in nginx: I'm not so skilled in nginx: just for this I was here to ask and try to find an answer that maybe someone more skilled than me can easy provide. But ok you are right, I'll try to redirect my search elsewhere :)

Comment: @MXT That's exactly why the question hasn't been closed - hopefully someone who knows the answer will come along and share their knowledge :) Unfortunately, due to the subject and difficulty in reproducing the problem (having to have Redirect installed, for example) it might take a while if it happens at all. Don't give up on it totally though, you might well still get a response here

Comment: Redirect shouldn't rely on server config.  It just sets up router entries for your redirects and serves up a 301.  In other words, I never have to adjust Apache for it.  In fact, I use it because I can let others manage it without bugging me :)

Comment: I retracted my close vote. I still think that solution is more probable in issue queue or on more server-oriented site, but oh well - I can't deny the truth in arguments here in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, someone redirected me to the right place

Here's the missing code that does the trick:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            error_page 418 = @rewrite;
            recursive_error_pages on;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^[^=](.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;

            if ( $uri = /index.php ) {
                    break;
            }

            if ( !-e $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    return 418;
            }

            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal

(link suggested in https://groups.drupal.org/node/405038)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem : migrating old site with php extension in Urls, and using [Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) to preserve SEO, nginx returned "*File not found*".

The above solution did not work for my config. Instead that one did the trick :

```
location ~ \.php$|^/update.php {
    #old urls with php extension redirect
    if ($request_uri ~ .*.php.*) {
      error_page 404 =  @rewrite;
    }

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```